# Node.js Callback not returning value to the calling function. Just timing out

Tags: node.js

So I think I have this correct but for some reason it is not executing the way I would think.  I am just wanting to decode the JWT Token and pass the data back.  Here is the code:

```
var jwtToken = function(message, callback) {
    var tokenArray = message.headers['authorization'];
    var array = tokenArray.toString().split(' ');

    if (array[0] == 'Bearer') {
        var token = array[1];
    } else {
        return callback.status(401).json({message: "bad json token"});
    }

    var map = JSON.parse(process.env.AUTH0_SECRET);

    var decoded = jwt2.decode(token, {complete: true});
    console.log('PAYLOAD:');
    console.log(decoded.payload);
    var clientId = decoded.payload.aud;
    var secret = map[clientId];

    //console.log('ENVIRONMENT SECRET: ' + map);
    //console.log('CLIENT ID: ' + clientId);
    //console.log('MAPPED SECRET: ' + secret);

    jwt2.verify(token, secret, function(err, decode){
        if (err) {
            callback.status(401).json({message: "JSON is incorrect or expired"})
        } else {
            callback = decode;
        }
    });
};

//route to make sure that the API works
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    jwtToken(req, function(data){
       console.log(data);
       res.json({ message: 'You are connected to the API  ' + data})
    });
});
```

What I would expect is that I pass in the request into the jwtToken function and I would get back the decoded Token in the callback.  I would then send the Response with the message and the decoded Token.  What I am getting is the data in the logs from the jwtToken call but then it keeps running till it times out.  I am just not sure what I messed up in the Callback that would stop it from sending the result back.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: So in the `console.log(data)` you can see the decoded token?   My guess is it can't see the `res` in the callback.    I guess one easy way to verify that would be to log the `res` object to the console within the callback and see if you get undefined.  If so, you might need to consider either consider passing in the `res` or adding in promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not *calling* the `callback` anywhere. Just *assigning* it to `decode`. You need to do:

```
callback(decode);
```

Assuming `decode` is the value that you want in your `data` in the `callback`.

Comment: Yep that worked.  Once I made the callback(decode) then the callback was working.  I knew I was doing something wrong.  So another question would be the for the err
callback.status(401).json({message: 'blah'})
would that also go back in the callback?

Comment: Nope. You'll actually get an error that `status` is not a function. You might want to do `callback({status: 401, message: blah})`, then do checks in the callback.